# Show there is a value where the polynomial has a root

Tags: calculus

> Let $$P_n(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+...+c_nx^n$$
>
> Show that in the interval $[0,1]$ there is one value when the polynomial get the value $0$ if it is known that $c_0+\frac{c_1}{2}+\frac{c_2}{3}+\cdots+\frac{c_n}{n+1}=0$

If I integrate $P_n(x)$ I get $c_0x+\frac{c_1}{2}x^2+\frac{c_2}{3}x^3+...+\frac{c_n}{n+1}x^{n+1}$ which are the coefficients I know that that are sum is $0$.

But what can I can conclude on the original polynomial?

Comment: Note that your integral is  $0$ at $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so the integral is a $y=0$?

Comment: if P(x) is the derivative of Q(x), and Q(0) = Q(1), what does Rolle's theorem imply about P(x)?

Comment: Now use the hint of xpaul. If $F(x)$ is your integral, then $F(0)=F(1)=0$, so by the MVT there is a number $c$ between $0$ and $1$ such that $F'(c)=0$.

Comment: @DougM there dearivate as a place where it get $0$ and the derivative is $P(x)$, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the Rolle Theorem and you will get the answer.

Comment: I know the function get any value between 0 and 1, I need to show it is negative and positive value in the interval for it

Comment: I believe you have a good idea here, but expressing it such a cryptic fashion may not help most Readers, including the OP.  If you want to give an Answer, more detail would be appropriate.  Otherwise consider leaving the above as a Comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Say $F(x)=\int P_n(x) dx$

Now observe that,

1. $F(x)$ is continuous in $(0,1)$
2. $F(x)$ is differentiable in $[0,1$] and
3. $F(0)=F(1)=0$

Hence, $F(x)$ satisfies the conditions of [**Rolle's Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem).

So there exists at least one $c \in (0,1)$ such that $F'(c)=0$. 
Or in other words, there exists at least one $c \in (0,1)$ such that $P_n(c)=0$.

Hope this helps.